# Collective noun for words that describe something they themself contain or are

Tags: collective-nouns

Is there a collective noun for words that describe something that this word itself contains or is?

Here are some examples of what I mean:

- ‘noun’ is a noun itself;
- ‘háček’ contains a letter with a háček;
- ‘plurals’ is plural itself.

Comment: You will find the answer to this question here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210942/collective-noun-for-words-that-describe-something-they-themself-contain-or-are

Comment: You are referring me to my own question…

Comment: That would be @MarvMills creating a self-referential joke.

Comment: Haha, okay, I see. Now that there is an answer, they're not wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a word is **autological** and can be called an **autonym**.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I am actually somewhat surprised there is a word for this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word

Comment: I am unsure where words like ‘vowel’ and ‘háček’ fit in. They don't seem to be autological, because they do not describe themselves, but merely a part of themselves. Moreover, ‘letters’ is autological, but as far as I can tell ‘letter’ is not, because it does not describe itself entirely; only a part of itself. Is there a separate term for words that are not quite autological, but still do describe a part of themselves?