# Is there a word that describes the phenomenon of a word being an example of what it is?

Tags: single-word-requests

According to Wikipedia, "A mondegreen is a mishearing or misinterpretation of a phrase as a result of near-homophony, in a way that gives it a new meaning"

"Mondegreen" is also an *example* of a mondegreen, because it is a mishearing of "laid him on the green"

My question is this: Is there a word for this? That is, is there a word that describes the phenomenon of a word being an example of what it is?  Are there other instances of this?

To provide an analogous example, onomatopoeia characterizes a word which sounds like the sound it describes (ex, boom, chirp).

[This question,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146424/word-for-phrases-that-are-examples-of-what-they-describe) thought related,  is different, I think.

Thanks!

Comment: Another possible duplicate [Collective noun for words that describe something they themself contain or are](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210942/collective-noun-for-words-that-describe-something-they-themself-contain-or-are/210943#210943)

Answer (score 2):

It's an [autological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word) word; perhaps *autolog* might be an acceptable noun formation (though I'm unaware that such a word has been proposed, or used):

> An **autological** word (also called **homological** word) is a word that expresses a property that it also possesses. ... The word "short" is short, "noun" is a noun, "English" is English, "pentasyllabic" has five syllables, "word" is a word

The Wikipedia article, in fact, specifically mentions *mondegreen* as autological:

> One source of autological words are archetypal words (ostensive definitions) – words chosen to describe a phenomenon by using an example of the phenomenon, which are thus necessarily autological. One such example is a *mondegreen* – a mishearing of a phrase, which itself is based on a mishearing of "And laid him on the green" as "And Lady Mondegreen".